# I want to get the total of 3 or more column in one select query

Tags: mysql

example query:
i create a query that get the total in one month and i want to add the 3 column

```
SELECT 
            SUM(vatPrivate) AS vatPrivate,
            SUM(vatGovernment) AS vatGovernment,
            SUM(vatZero) AS vatZero

            FROM transaction gl
            WHERE (gl.entryDate) BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-29'
FROM `transaction`;
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database name. Some sample data with your expected output from them would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "new" columns aren't available yet. Wrap the query up as a derived table (the subquery):

```
select dt.*, vatPrivate + vatGovernment + vatExempt
from
(
    SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN entryDate BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-31'
                    THEN vatPrivate END) AS vatPrivate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN entryDate BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-31'
                    THEN vatGovernment END) AS vatGoverment,
        SUM(CASE WHEN entryDate BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-31'
                    THEN vatExempt END) AS vatExempt
    FROM `transaction`
) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql select syntax is executed in unknown order, so you can't use select aliases in same select. You sholud use CTE or subquery to do this. For future: you sholud tag sql db engine in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is just to repeat the `SUM` expressions.

```
SELECT SUM(vatPrivate) AS vatPrivate,
       SUM(vatGovernment) AS vatGovernment,
       SUM(vatZero) AS vatZero,
       SUM(vatPrivate) + SUM(vatGovernment) + SUM(vatZero) AS vatTotal
FROM transaction gl
WHERE (gl.entryDate) BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-29'
```

You can probably rely on the query optimiser to notice you've repeated them and not compute them twice. If you want to be certain they're not re-computed, use a subquery:

```
SELECT vatPrivate, vatGovernment, vatZero,
       vatPrivate + vatGovernment + vatZero AS vatTotal
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(vatPrivate) AS vatPrivate,
           SUM(vatGovernment) AS vatGovernment,
           SUM(vatZero) AS vatZero
    FROM transaction gl
    WHERE (gl.entryDate) BETWEEN '2019-11-05' AND '2019-11-29'
) sums
```